# what's the difference between "ip a" and "ifconfig" under SUSE 11

Tags: linux, suse

I found the output of the two commands are different and it seems that "ip a" will list more interface's infomation that ipconfig, so the simple question is why? from my understanding, "ip a" is just kind of alias for ifconfig.

Answer (score 2):

`ip` from *iproute2* is intended to be a replacement for the older `ifconfig`, `route` and `arp` *net-tools* programs, providing a more consistent interface. It also supports various new features not supported by *net-tools* such as policy routing, multiple IPv4 addresses per interface (without the need for :aliases), or CIDR instead of subnet masks. (As far as I know, *net-tools* haven't been maintained since 2001.)

Answer (score 0):

They're very similar commands. The exact sets of information they list is not precisely the same. `ifconfig`, for example, lists packet counts. `ip a`, for example, lists IPv4 addresses not associated with aliases.

Comment: `ip -stat link` lists packet counts.

Answer (score 0):

`ifconfig` is just to configure an interface, while `ip` can additionally set routes, tunnels, monitor an interface and more. Compare `man ifconfig` with `man ip`.